# Make a View partial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view called drawGraph , this is accessed through the controller via;

```
@Html.ActionLink("DrawGraph", "drawGraph", new {id =item.data})
```

When i use this link the page loads on a new page (as it would) i would like to display it as a part of the page that the link is on, is there any easy way to achive this?

my controller looks like this;

```
   public ActionResult drawGraph(string data)
    {
         *Bunch of code
         return View(chart);
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, however you need to use Ajax, luckily ASP.NET MVC provides some nice convenience methods like [Ajax.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("DrawGraph", "drawGraph", new {id =item.data},  
                 new AjaxOptions
                            {
                                UpdateTargetId = "yourDiv",
                                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            })

<div id="yourDiv"> </div>
```

Then you need to return a partial view from your action with [PartialView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.partialview%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
public ActionResult drawGraph(string data)
{

    //Bunch of code    
    return PartialView(chart);
}
```

You should not forget to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` in your layout/view in order to the Ajax helpers work.

Comment: Thank you so much nemesv! it really made my day! Its hard to search when you dont know what to search for, i will read more about the ajax.actionlink :)